# how to insert serialized data into database?

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

here my code-

```
$things = serialize($_POST['things']);
echo $things;

require 'database.php';

$q = "INSERT INTO tblslider(src) values($things)";
mysql_query($q, $link);

if($result)
{
echo "Slider saved successfully.";
}
```

**Output-**
`a:4:{i:0;s:10:"651603.jpg";i:1;s:11:"7184512.jpg";i:2;s:11:"3659637.jpg";i:3;s:10:"569839.jpg";}v`

it means I am getting the record properly but why it it not getting saved in db??

Comment: What *exactly* do you intend to insert to the DB? You say that you are "getting the record properly" suggesting that you're happy with writing the value of `$things` to the DB. *However*, this doesn't match your comments on several answers below. Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: @jensgram: if he can't be bothered to accept answers in previous questions, he can't be bothered to elaborate

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You forgot quotes around `$things`:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO tblslider(src) values('" . mysql_real_escape_string($things) . "')";
```

The [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) is really the *least* you should *ever* do!

Also as @sanders [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183228/how-to-insert-serialized-data-into-database/4183250#4183250), you should always output your complete query (via `print_r()` or `var_dump()`) as a first step in debugging.

---

I prefer to build queries like this to enhance readability:

```
$q = sprintf(
         'INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES ("%s")',
         mysql_real_escape_string($things)
     );
```

That is, whenever I absolutely *have* to build and escape them myself. You should really have a look at [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

---

**EDIT**
Comments in this thread suggests that OP actually wants to insert `651603.jpg,7184512.jpg,3659637.jpg,569839.jpg` into the database. In that case [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) could be [used](http://www.ideone.com/q6Gay) (provided that `$_POST['things']` *only* contains items to insert!):

```
$q = sprintf(
         'INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES ("%s")',
         mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['things']))
     );
```

Note, that I'm using `$_POST['things']` directly here. No `serialize()`. (I did, however, not realize this erro until just now.)

Comment: `var_dump($q)` id giving this value INSERT INTO tblslider(src) values(a:4:{i:0;s:10:"651603.jpg";i:1;s:11:"7184512.jpg";i:2;s:11:"3659637.jpg";i:3;s:10:"569839.jpg";})" v

Comment: it should be like insert tblname(src) values(122.jpg, 5646.jpg.....) seems insert query is wrong

Comment: @ppp See update - and my reply on your comment to @sanders's answer.

Comment: I am getting this error after putting your code `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in D:\Hosting\6448289\html\admin\setSlider.php on line 13` line no 13 is mysql_real_es...

Comment: @ppp Yes, I forgot a comma in the `implode()` call. Should have been `mysql_real_escape_string(implode(',', $_POST['things']))` - see updated answer.

Answer (score 5):

This question is quite old, but I feel like it's time for a little necromancy. The accepted answer by @jensgram is not wrong, but saying `mysql_real_escape_string` is *the least* you could do implies there is a much better solution. Well there is.

## PHP Data Objects

[PDOs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php). These bad boys provide an abstraction layer for your database access, so it works with a lot of other databases not just MySQL, and can improve performance when the same query is run many times. Nut this is not why you need them.

### Security

Escaping stuff is hard. Either it is obscure how to do it in a specific context or you just forget to do it. The worst thing is that you will not get any errors from forgetting it, and just move on like nothing happened. And you just contributed to the sorry state internet security is in.

With using PDOs properly (e.g. no string concatenation) however will ensure that you will not mess up properly escaping stuff while building DB queries.

You will want to read this: [(The only proper) PDO tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo).

Basically you can prepare an sql statement BEFORE replacing ANY parameters in it. The SQL syntax will be fixed and cannot be broken by bad/no escaping or maliciously forged requests.

### So how to do this

At first you need a connection, just like in the regular mysql driver.

```
$host = '127.0.0.1';
$db   = 'test';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$charset = 'utf8';

$dsn = "mysql:host=$host;dbname=$db;charset=$charset";
$opt = [
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
];
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $opt);
```

As you can see there are settings, error modes, fetch modes. It worths reading what each setting does but for now just leave it as it is. At the end of it all, you have the $pdo variable you can use.

```
$query = "INSERT INTO tblslider(src) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
```

At this point we got our statement. Nothing came from external sources yet, it is an INSERT statement.

```
$things = serialize($_POST['things'])
$stmt->execute([ $things ]); //execute
```

There are other ways to bind the ?-s to parameters, also you can use named parameters too for clarity, but this suffices for now.

That's it: no fancy escaping but no possibility for SQL injection either.

Answer (score 2):

Normally, I will serialize then base64_encode to eliminate surprises and "standardize" the input.  For example:

```
$things = base64_encode(serialize($_POST['things']));
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO...";
```

Then, when you want to grab it, simply reverse the process.

```
$query_result = mysql_query("SELECT FROM ...");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_result);
$retrieved_value = unserialize(base64_decode($row['src']);
```

Answer (score 0):

place an `var_dump($q)` before `mysql_query(...)` 
You can then examine your query.

Comment: `var_dump($q)` id giving this value INSERT INTO tblslider(src) values(a:4:{i:0;s:10:"651603.jpg";i:1;s:11:"7184512.jpg";i:2;s:11:"3659637.jpg";i:3;s:10:"569839.jpg";})" v

Comment: it should be like insert tblname(src) values(122.jpg, 5646.jpg.....) seems insert query is wrong

Comment: @ppp In that case I think you've misunderstood what `serialize()` does. Have a look at `implode()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a string to the database, so don't forget to add quotes to your query:

```
$q = "INSERT INTO tblslider(src) values('$things')";
```

Also make sure to filter the string to avoid SQL-Injection Attacks.